# SOLID in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I would like to ask you about SOLID principles in Laravel, actually it's question about single responsibility principle.

Let's assume I have **ExcelController** class where I import users to database. I also have **UserController** where I have *createUser* method. The problem is that ExcelController cannot extend from UserController, because it already extends from Controller. So in this case should I create UserTrait and there put the createUser  method?

What's the best approach?

Comment: `createUser` should be a method of a Model.

Comment: Why You Don't Use The User Model ??

Comment: Yep guys, thank you, I should place it in Model.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd rather suggest you create service `User` and have all methods inside this service. And from `ExcelController` call:

```
(new UserService())->import($parameters);
```

And from `UserController` call:

```
(new UserService())->create($parameters);
```

In laravel you can use `Service Container` and write something like:

```
$userService = $this->app->make('UserService');
$userService->import($parameters);
// or
$userService->create($parameters);
```

Comment: What are the pros of using this solution instead of putting the create method in User model?

Comment: You will have 1 layer for all stuff like that and don't mix it with models.
Also in case you have method which is related as much to model 1 as to model 2 - it is not clear where this method must be placed in model 1 or in model 2, but with this approach it is only 1 layer - `service`.

Comment: @forexknight Happy to help!)